# how to print something to jtextfield if i have condition

Tags: java, arrays, jtextarea

I have an array (`logic.res`) where I stored the results of some calculations, and I want to print on a `JTextarea (rez)` a result (an element of that array). I want to insert before that result a single sentence. Which sentence is chosen depends on which element of that array is the result (`i` determines the result):

```
 public void initComponents() {
calculate.addActionListener((ActionEvent p) -> {

        try {
            if (radioButton1.isSelected()) {
                double condition1 = Double.parseDouble(txtCondition1.getText());
                double condition2 = Double.parseDouble(txtConition2.getText());
                double condition3 = Double.parseDouble(txtCondition3.getText());
                double[] conditions = {condition1, condition2, condition3};
                double shift1 = Double.parseDouble(txtShift1.getText());
                double shift2 = Double.parseDouble(txtShift2.getText());
                double shift3 = Double.parseDouble(txtShift3.getText());
                double workingDays = 360;
               YearWorkingHurs yearWorkingHours = new YearWorkingHurs(workingDays);
                double[] shifts = {shift1, shift2, shift3};
                double capacity1 = object.getCapacity();
                double capacity2 = object2.getCapacity();
                Logic logic = new Logic(capacity1, capacity2, conditions, shifts);
                logic.solution();
                long[] solution = logic.rez;
                for (int i = 0; i < logic.rez.length; i++) {long[] solution = logic.res;
        for (int i = 0; i < logic.res.length; i++) {
            if (logic.res[i] >= 20000000 && logic.res[i] < 23000000) {

                long temp = logic.res[i];
                if (i == 0) {
                    rez.append("The choosen capacity has been fulfilled in good condition in one shift" + "\n");
                    rez.append(String.valueOf(temp) + "\n");                                        
                    draw.setEnabled(true);
                } else if (i == 1) {
                    rez.append("The choosen capacity has been fulfilled in good condition in 2 shifts" + "\n");
                    rez.append(String.valueOf(temp) + "\n");
                    draw.setEnabled(true);
                } else if (i == 2) {
                    rez.append("The choosen capacity has been fulfilled in good condition in 3 shifts" + "\n");
                    rez.append(String.valueOf(temp) + "\n");
                    draw.setEnabled(true);
                } else if (i == 3) {
                    rez.append("The choosen capacity has been fulfilled in semi-good condition in one shift" + "\n");
                    rez.append(String.valueOf(temp) + "\n");
                    draw.setEnabled(true);
                } else if (i == 4) {
                    rez.append("The choosen capacity has been fulfilled in semi-good condition in 2 shifts" + "\n");
                    rez.append(String.valueOf(temp) + "\n");
                    draw.setEnabled(true);
                } else if (i == 5) {
                    rez.append("The choosen capacity has been fulfilled in semi-good condition in 3 shifts" + "\n");
                    rez.append(String.valueOf(temp) + "\n");
                    draw.setEnabled(true);
                } else if (i == 6) {
                    rez.append("The choosen capacity has been fulfilled in bad condition in one shift" + "\n");
                    rez.append(String.valueOf(temp) + "\n");
                    draw.setEnabled(true);
                } else if (i == 7) {
                    rez.append("The choosen capacity has been fulfilled in bad condition in 2 shifts" + "\n");
                    rez.append(String.valueOf(temp) + "\n");
                    draw.setEnabled(true);
                } else if (i == 8) {
                    rez.append("The choosen capacity has been fulfilled in bad condition in 3 shifts" + "\n");
                    rez.append(String.valueOf(temp) + "\n");

                }

            } else {

            }
        }

    }


    }catch(Exception ex){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane,"Greska u proračunu,proverite unose");
               }

            obrisi.setEnabled(true);
        });
```

But with this code I didn't get the desired sentence, because this is both referencing to the number of elements in my array, and to the number of lines in my `JTextArea`.

The text that I want to get in my `JTextArea` is, for example, the result that is in the 8th element of the array, but because it is printed in line 3, it got the sentence from `i==3` instead of `i==8`.

Comment: Can't you put the sentences "The choosen" in some `chosen` array, use `chosen[i]` and remove all the `if`s? Regarding your question, can you clarify (you may be looking for `break`, but I'm not sure)?

Comment: yes, but in that case i need to have the same number of elements as array of the results?

Comment: rez is JTextArea ,and i wanted to print before the result but i do not want that sentence from condition 3 gets printed i want if result is 8 that sentence from 8 condition to be printed.Thanks for the help

Comment: With every elemt of the array res.So just depends in which line it is printed so if it's printed in 5 then it will be printed sentence  i==5

Comment: i will add whole method over here.just a second

Comment: you are using variable name `i` for both of your `for` loops try using `i` and `j` as variable names for the loops to distinguissh which `i` you want your `if` condition to check

Comment: Next time, rather than using an if-else ladder, consider using a `switch` using `i` as the control variable: `switch(i)`

Comment: @JackKirby , thanks for the advice i implemented switch, one more thing, i am thinking to move everything bellow calculate.AddActionLIstener to another class.but whnever i try to check my program it shows  exception.Why is it like that?